# Problems with compiling drivers for rtl8192cu

Tags: kernel, driver, realtek

I'm trying to use realtek 8188cu module in concurrent mode(both station and AP mode simultaneously). I downloaded the driver source files from here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/204050d0eafb565b68abf512710036c10ef1bd23/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8192cu

And I modified the include/autoconf.h: enabled the commented out line: `#define CONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE 1`

i'm running the latest stable release for raspbian lite: `4.9.59-v7+`
I downloaded the linux kernel files by running `rpi-source --skip-gcc`

And I built the kernel module using the command: `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r )/build M=$(pwd) modules`
The compilation succeeded without giving me any errors, but upon inspecting the 8192cu.ko file generated after compilation, I find out that its compiled to the wrong kernel version. Below is the vermagic information when I ran `modinfo ./8192cu.ko`:
`vermagic:       4.9.58-v7+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8`

Tried modprobing the .ko file. Did not work.

But I don't even have kernel sources for 4.9.58-v7+.. What is going on? Can somebody help me to compile the driver successfully and to get it working with latest raspbian stable release?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't even have kernel sources for 4.9.58-v7+..

The source tree is on github: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux

However, there are only branches for each minor version, and the current sublevel if you look in the Makefile for 4.9.y is 4.9.80.

If you look at [the history of the Makefile](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commits/rpi-4.9.y/Makefile), though, you'll find the commit from upstream for 4.9.59 was October 27 last year.  The closest [release from the Rpi tree](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/releases) is October 29, and if you download that it is indeed 4.9.59.

Running `make bcm2709_defconfig` should give you the configuration for v7+, and if you are lucky, building a module against that will match your kernel.